# German Carcassonne fan expansions - available in English?

Tags: house-rules, carcassonne, expansions, reference

I was browsing the Hans im Glück website and found two 'official' [fan-made expansions](http://www.hans-im-glueck.de/carcassonne/fan-erweiterungen/) for Carcassonne.

The expansions are called:

- *[Die Stadttore](http://www.hans-im-glueck.de/carcassonne/fan-erweiterungen/die-stadttore/)* (The City Gates)
  [image: Carcassonne tile showing a city gate]
- *[Der Osterhase](http://www.hans-im-glueck.de/carcassonne/fan-erweiterungen/der-osterhase/)* (The Easter Bunny)
  [image: Carcassonne tiles showing an Easter bunny and Easter eggs]

Unfortunately the site is in German and so are the rules, both for *[Die Stadttore](http://www.hans-im-glueck.de/fileadmin/data_archive/Downloads/CC-Fanerweiterungen/CarcStadttore_Regel_Web.pdf)* and *[Der Osterhase](http://www.hans-im-glueck.de/fileadmin/data_archive/Regeln_Mini-Erw._Promos/CarcOstern_Regel_kleiner.pdf)*.

**Where can I find the English rules?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick <strike>Google</strike> web search reveals [this post](http://carcassonnecentral.com/forum/index.php?topic=2219.0) for the Easter Festival (yes, it's the same author although a different name). The full rules for both expansions can be found in the downloads sections of Carcassonne Central (you'll need to register, but it's free to do so).

- [Easter Festival - Rules](http://www.carcassonnecentral.com/community/index.php?action=downloads;sa=view;down=178)
- [Easter Festival - Tiles](http://www.carcassonnecentral.com/community/index.php?action=downloads;sa=view;down=179)
- [City Gates Rules - English translation](http://www.carcassonnecentral.com/community/index.php?action=downloads;sa=view;down=290)

Comment: Those are behind a login, on a site I don't know, and I can't get past the captcha...

Comment: @freekvd That registration form is evil indeed. Here is the link to those 3 files, active for 7 days: http://we.tl/pJIIt4uocc